# HTML entities inside script tag not converted?

Tags: javascript, xml

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test()    {
        alert('&lt;span&gt;blah&lt;span&gt;');
    }
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="test();">First</a><br />
<a href="#" onclick="alert('&lt;span&gt;blah&lt;span&gt;');">Second</a><br />
Third: &lt;span&gt;blah&lt;span&gt;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LPYTZ/

Why is the first result different? Are `<script>` tags somehow excluded from entity conversion?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In HTML, script and style elements are [defined in the DTD as containing CDATA](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html#Script). This means that entities and tags are ignored until the parser hits something that looks like an end tag.

[XHTML is different](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.8) and entities and tags inside those elements function as normal — but only when parsed as XHTML. You can explicitly mark content as CDATA with `<![CDATA[ … ]]>`.

Browsers will treat XHTML served as text/html using HTML rules which leads to a big ball of nasty as you try to write code that is correct under both sets of rules.

The simplest way to avoid problems is to keep scripts in external files and use the `src` attribute to include them.

Comment: As I already *had* XHTML (in jsfiddle, too) +1 for the "Browsers will treat XHTML served as text/html using HTML rules" part.

Comment: @AndreKR: It’s the MIME media type that matters, not the content.

Comment: What about HTML5?

Comment: @PedroGimeno — HTML 5 is HTML (except when it is XHTML).

Comment: @Quentin, HTML 5 may be HTML, but [it is not SGML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16185880/html5-is-not-based-on-sgml-so-what-is-it-based-on-then) and therefore there's no DTD for it. Your reply references a DTD that does not exist for HTML5. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: @PedroGimeno — The rules are the same, even though the means of expressing them is different.

Comment: I was kind of hoping a reference to a normative source that stated this. I've dug into it myself, it's interspersed in the syntax description but the gist of it is here: https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/syntax.html#script-data-state - note that the only special characters are NULL and `<`; the rest including `&` are emitted verbatim. Other states may apply after opening a `<!--` comment, but in any case there's no special interpretation of `&` at least until an end tag is seen.

Comment: @PedroGimeno — Well yes. That's the point. Special interpretation of `&` happens *outside* scripts.

Answer (score 16):

Yes, the [content model of `STYLE` and `SCRIPT`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-cdata) is special:

> Although the `STYLE` and `SCRIPT` elements use CDATA for their data model, for these elements, CDATA must be handled differently by user agents. Markup and entities must be treated as raw text and passed to the application as is. The first occurrence of the character sequence "`</`" (end-tag open delimiter) is treated as terminating the end of the element's content. In valid documents, this would be the end tag for the element.

Comment: Ha! So, to have that character sequence in a JS string, you need to do something like: `'<' + '/'` or `'\u003C/'`