# Escaping JSON in JSPX

Tags: javascript, json, jsp, jsp-tags, jspx

I want to initialize a Javascript variable from some JSON (generated via Jackson) in my JSPX, something like this:

```
<script>
var x = <c:out value="${myJson}" />;
</script>
```

But the output I get looks like:

```
<script>
var x = {&#034;foo&#034;:&#034bar&#034};
</script>
```

I see what you did there, HTML-escaping the string. Obviously, I can't leave it completely unescaped because angle brackets in the data could break the page. But I don't really need all the quotes to be escaped, since I'm not putting the JSON within an attribute value, do I?

<strike>Now, this looks like it would be a perfectly valid way to write a script in HTML, just needlessly complicated (like, say, replacing spaces with `&#32;`).</strike> As it turns out, it works just fine in XHTML, but with an HTML content type, I get an error, both in Firefox and IE. I'm not sure of the rationale, but that's how it is.

So, what's the best approach here? Do I really want to simply escape angle brackets but not escape double quotes, or are there any other gotchas? Is there a tag out there that would replace `c:out` (I know there are Spring tags for escaping Javascript, but that's still not the right kind of escaping)? How do people get this to work?

BTW, yes, I could make a separate AJAX call, but an extra round trip just to work around this problem seems silly.

**UPDATE**

I had a lot to learn about CDATA vs. PCDATA and how [HTML is different from XHTML](http://hixie.ch/advocacy/xhtml). Here I thought JSPX would make [polyglot markup](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-xhtml-author-guide/) easy, but it turns out to be, as someone put it, [a big ball of nasty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4227942/970288).

For HTML, the `<script>` element has a [CDATA content model](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?612147-PCDATA-vs-CDATA-just-means-to-be-parsed-or-not-to-be-parsed-as-XHTML-or-HTML&s=839727c348915a9c06b6aea10cbe1e91&p=4229368&viewfull=1#post4229368) (not to be confused with CDATA sections), which means nothing can be escaped, but `</` *must* be absolutely avoided.

In the special case of JSON, where end tags can only occur within a quoted string, this therefore means the safe way to escape is to use Javascript (rather than HTML) escaping and replace `</` with `<\/`.

For XHTML (if you care about such things) on the other hand, you just XML-escape everything as usual (`&` becomes `&amp;`, etc.) and it all works beautifully. A compatible solution would have to use CDATA with guarding comments (`<!--/*--><![CDATA[/*><!--*/` etc.) around the entire `<script>` body and then escape any occurrences of `]]>` within the JSON; furthermore, I'd still escape `</` too just to be safe. Big ball of nasty, indeed, but at least it can be automated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, answering my own question here, after much research and no real help.

Based my "update" above, the most straightforward way targeting HTML is just:

```
<script>
var x = ${fn:replace(myJson, "\</", "\<\\/")};
</script>
```

Ugly but simple.

This will *not* yield valid XML or XHTML, unfortunately. If you really need that, the original `c:out` will work fine, though it will *not* yield valid HTML. And if you really need a single solution to work on both, you probably need a custom taglib (or TAGX) that will either switch from the content type or do all of the following:

- wrap the script body in a [comment-guarded](http://hixie.ch/advocacy/xhtml) CDATA section
- replace each `</` with `<\/`
- replace each `]]>` with `]]\>`

Answer (score 4):

set `escapeXml=false`

```
<c:out value="${myJson}" escapeXml="false"/>
```