# Are html codes allowed in HTML attributes?

Tags: html, attributes

Is this a valid HTML code?

I replaced / with it's html-code `&sol;`
Refer: https://www.htmlsymbols.xyz/unicode

`<a href=&sol;sample2.htm>Using html code for slash</a>`

When I try this code in chrome, it does work, the link is shown properly. Wondering if this is valid?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it okay to use HTML entities in attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444605/is-it-okay-to-use-html-entities-in-attributes)

Answer (score 0):

Slashes do work in HTML `<a href>` tags. You should probably use those to keep your `<a href>` links shorter.

So you can have

```
<a href="/sample2.htm">Using html code for slash</a>
```

Also a tip, in `<a href>` you need quotes when hyperlinking to another webpage, like I put mine.

Comment: Also, using the ```&sol;``` attribute might not always work.

Comment: I am under impression that `<a href="/&sol;sample2.htm">Using html code for slash</a>` works same as `<a href="sample2.htm">Using html code for slash</a>`