# How to inject variable content with font-family into Thymeleaf style tag?

Tags: thymeleaf, html-email

I use Thymeleaf for email templates. Since HTML email templates are a bit of a pain in the *ss, I want to declare some values in variables and then use them whenever needed inside the template. For example, you have to put into each style attribute for tags holding text the complete font-family.

So my approach is something like this:

```html
<div th:with="fontFamilySans='font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, \'Segoe UI Adjusted\', \'Segoe UI\', \'Liberation Sans\', Roboto, \'Helvetica Neue\', Arial, sans-serif;'">

  <p th:style="|margin: 0; padding: 0; ${fontFamilySans}|">Aloha from Hawaii</p>

</div>
```

Unfortunaltely, doing it this way the single quotes get escaped:

```html
<p style="margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, &#39;Segoe UI Adjusted&#39;, &#39;Segoe UI&#39;, &#39;Liberation Sans&#39;, Roboto, &#39;Helvetica Neue&#39;, Arial, sans-serif;">Aloha from Hawaii</p>
```

Is there any way to tell Thymeleaf to no escape the quotes but treat them as valid HTML code?

**Many thanks for any help**

Comment: Not a user of Thymeleaf, but, what about `[(${fontFamilySans})]`, based on https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.1/usingthymeleaf.html#expression-inlining

Comment: `&#39;` is valid HTML... does it not work in the email client you tested? [https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRxXS.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRxXS.png).

Comment: @Nathan: tested, but same result

Comment: @Metroids: Unfortunately Thymeleaf renders this quotes as escaped text, so the result in the HTML Source code is this: https://imgur.com/7QrYYk1

Comment: @Metroids: is this really valid HTML code? I know that HTML is built to be as lean as possible, so even when things might work it could be that it's not valid.

Comment: Just to be clear: everywhere I would have to use let's say quotes, double-quotes, opening or closing brackets, I always can use the HTML code as well and the browsers will render them correctly?

Comment: According to [W3C](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes) -- `You can use a character escape to represent any Unicode character in HTML, XHTML or XML using only ASCII characters.`

Comment: Thank you for your help @Metroids. With additionally help of TimRoberts I finally could get some light into my brain and ended up here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12444605/13609359 . What a ride when you don't know what to ask and where to look at. Anyhow, life is a learning journey... ;)